# Defining an SDE in Matlab in which the Components Are Functions of Other SDEs

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, differential-equations, stochastic

I am trying to create an SDE model in Matlab with the [`sde`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/sde.html) function in the Econometrics toolbox. From looking at the examples on the website, the basic case seems simple enough in that an equation like

`dX(t) = 0.1 X(t) dt + 0.3 X(t) dW(t)`

can be defined by first creating anonymous functions and then using those in the SDE equation as seen below (where the variables used in the functions are previously defined):

```
F = @(t,X) 0.1 * X;
G = @(t,X) 0.3 * X;
obj = sde(F, G)    % dX = F(t,X)dt + G(t,X)dW
```

I was hoping to do something just a bit more complicated in which the drift term of the SDE I would like to model is a function of another SDE. Specifically, the equation is

`dY(t) / Y(t) = G(t) dt + sigma dW(t)`

Where G(t) is another SDE I've already defined. Would someone be able to give me a sense of what the equation for the drift term (corresponding to `F` in the code above) would be in this case?

Comment: This seems to be more of a math question than a programming one, no? Your `Y(t)` SDE appears to be nothing more than [geometric Brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) with time varying drift `G(t)`. The Econometrics toolbox has dedicated functions for common stochastic processes such as these ([`gbm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/gbm.html) in this case). These are simpler to use and likely much faster to simulate.

Comment: For the sake of full clarity, the G(t) wasn't meant to be just 0.3*X. I just put that up as an example of a simple SDE. What would be the code for defining G(t) and Y(t) be for Y(t) as defined above and `dG(t) = kappa * (mu - G(t)) dt + tau dW(t)`. Note that the Weiner processes for the two equations here are separate. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, your `dG(t)` looks like an [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck_process). Again, the Econometrics toolbox has a dedicated function for this process: [`hmv`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/hwv.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the Econometrics toolbox so I can't give you detailed code for it (most Matlab installs don't have this toolbox by default). However, your case is a pretty common so I imagine that it shouldn't be too hard to do what you need. You might consider [creating a service request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/index.html?s_tid=contact_us_support_cust_serv) with The MathWorks or posting a question at [Quant.StackExchange](http://quant.stackexchange.com). Make sure you're clear about the SDEs that you're interested in. Sorry that I can't help you more in that area.

Another way to simulate this coupled set of SDEs is to use my own [SDETools](https://github.com/horchler/SDETools) toolbox which is available for free on GitHub. These are quite straightforward if you have any experience with Matlab's ODE Suite functions such as `ode45`. SDETools also has dedicated functions for common stochastic process (e.g., geometric Brownian motion and Ornstein-Uhlenbeck) using their analytic solutions. Here is basic code with arbitrary parameter values to simulate your SDEs using the Euler-Maryama integrator function, [`sde_euler`](https://github.com/horchler/SDETools/blob/master/SDETools/sde_euler.m), in SDETools:

```
t0 = 0;
dt = 1e-2;
tf = 1e1;
tspan = t0:dt:tf; % Time vector
y0 = [1;1];       % Initial conditions

kappa = 10;
mu = 0;
tau = 1e-1;
sigma = 1e-2;
f = @(t,y)[kappa.*(mu-y(1));y(1).*y(2)]; % Drift
g = @(t,y)[tau;sigma.*y(2)];             % Diffusion

% Set random seed and type of stochastic integration
options = sdeset('RandSeed',1,'SDEType','Ito');

Y = sde_euler(f,g,tspan,y0,options); % Euler-Maruyama
figure;
plot(tspan,Y)
```

In fact, it's possible that the `sde` function in the Econometrics toolbox could itself take the two function handles, `f` and `g`, I created above.

Here's another way you can simulate the system (it may or may not be faster), this time using the [`sde_ou`](https://github.com/horchler/SDETools/blob/master/SDETools/sde_ou.m) function to first generate an OU process, which itself is independent of the other equation:

```
...

options = sdeset('RandSeed',1);
Y(:,1) = sde_ou(kappa,mu,tau,tspan,y0(1),options); % OU process

f = @(t,y)Y(round(t/dt)+1,1).*y; % Index into OU process as a function of t
g = @(t,y)sigma.*y;
options = sdeset('RandSeed',2,'SDEType','Ito');
Y(:,2) = sde_euler(f,g,tspan,y0(2),options); % Euler-Maruyama of just second equation

figure;
plot(tspan,Y)
```

Note that even the the same random seed is used for the OU process, the output of `Y(:,1)` will be slightly different for this and the `sde_euler` case because of the order in which the Wiener increments are generated internally. Again, you may well be able to do something similar using the function in the Econometrics toolbox.